# How to get Read-only Youtube API access

Tags: youtube-api

For YouTube APIs, the only scope that is document is http://gdata.youtube.com, which asks the user to grand full read/write access. Is there a scope that asks/grants read-only permissions OR just read permissions to Youtube Insight data?

Answer (score 6):

[v3 of the YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) now has support for a read-only scope: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly`

Tokens obtained with that scope won't work with the older v1/v2 of the API, though. You can only use them with v3 calls.

Answer (score 2):

Found out from one of the YouTube API guys (4/16/12):

"It's not possible with the current API, unfortunately. There's just a
single scope that grants full read/write access to the account. This
is a valid request, though, and I'll pass it along to the engineering
team. I can't make any promises about whether it will be implemented,
though."

Comment: Still no changes about this?

Answer (score 0):

The read-only analytics permission (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly) used to work under v2 as well and it's even in the docs: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v2/gdataAuthentication

However it doesn't work now and Google doesn't look very motivated to fix it: http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=3916