# Is it possible to limit the access given by a user so that it's read-only

Tags: youtube-api

I'm trying to use the YouTube Data API V2.0 to pull data insights for the videos/channels of our client. I have a developer key and a token that my client generates, and successfully figured out how to retrieve that information. My problem is, when my client uses the app for YouTube token generation, we are asking for an access that means EVERYTHING and to be able to "manage" their accounts.

This is a major concern for the client and they don't want us to have this kind of complete access. Is there a way to get a token generated with only read-only permission?

Thanks very much for any help!

Comment: V2 is deprecated and has NO read-only. But V3 has. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643190/how-to-get-read-only-youtube-api-access

Comment: Thanks for the quick revert Als. I went through the link and other documentation available and many people have mentioned that this is not working even in V3. Have you tried this.

Comment: No, i have never tried it myself. I was thinking of the scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly" which is for "View your YouTube account".  I'm using scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube" which is for "Manage your YouTube account". Besides this short description of the scope, i don't know the exact differences between them. There are even other YouTube scopes, but only 1 has "readonly" in its name.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used `https://googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly` as a scope; if you ask for just that scope during the initial oAuth flow (and NOT for `https://googleapis.com/auth/youtube` at the same time, as that is the management scope which will override the readonly scope), then you will get a 403 error whenever attempting an action that requires management permissions (inserting, uploading, updating, deleting).

The google-api clients for v3 handle this quite smoothly, if you're using them. If you have written your own oAuth flow control, just make sure you have the sole readonly scope when requesting the initial token.

**EDIT IN RESPONSE TO COMMENT**: To view this in action (I'll use javascript to show), you can create a simple demo using the [sample code](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript) provided by the API docs. Here's the general process:

1) In the Google API console, create a 'project' and authorize the YouTube API for that project (under the Services tab). Additionally,create a client ID for web applications (under the API access tab) and add in your domain as an authorized Javascript domain.

2) On your server, create and HTML file to serve as your interface (in this sample, it is designed to let you create a new playlist and add items to it). Here's the code, straight from the docs:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Playlist Updates</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="login-container" class="pre-auth">This application requires access to your YouTube account.
      Please <a href="#" id="login-link">authorize</a> to continue.
    </div>
    <div id="buttons">
      <button id="playlist-button" disabled onclick="createPlaylist()">Create a new Private Playlist</button>
      <br>
      <label>Current Playlist Id: <input id="playlist-id" value='' type="text"/></label>
      <br>
      <label>Video Id: <input id="video-id" value='GZG9G5txtaE' type="text"/></label><button onclick="addVideoToPlaylist()">Add to current playlist</button>
    </div>
    <h3>Playlist: <span id="playlist-title"></span></h3>
    <p id="playlist-description"></p>
    <div id="playlist-container">
      <span id="status">No Videos</span>
    </div>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="auth.js"></script>
    <script src="playlist_updates.js"></script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=googleApiClientReady"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

3) In that same location, create the script "playlist_updates.js" with this code (again, straight from the docs):

```
// Some variables to remember state.
var playlistId, channelId;

// Once the api loads call a function to get the channel information.
function handleAPILoaded() {
  enableForm();
}

// Enable a form to create a playlist.
function enableForm() {
  $('#playlist-button').attr('disabled', false);
}

// Create a private playlist.
function createPlaylist() {
  var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlists.insert({
    part: 'snippet,status',
    resource: {
      snippet: {
        title: 'Test Playlist',
        description: 'A private playlist created with the YouTube API'
      },
      status: {
        privacyStatus: 'private'
      }
    }
  });
  request.execute(function(response) {
    var result = response.result;
    if (result) {
      playlistId = result.id;
      $('#playlist-id').val(playlistId);
      $('#playlist-title').html(result.snippet.title);
      $('#playlist-description').html(result.snippet.description);
    } else {
      $('#status').html('Could not create playlist');
    }
  });
}

// Add a video id from a form to a playlist.
function addVideoToPlaylist() {
  addToPlaylist($('#video-id').val());
}

// Add a video to a playlist.
function addToPlaylist(id, startPos, endPos) {
  var details = {
    videoId: id,
    kind: 'youtube#video'
  }
  if (startPos != undefined) {
    details['startAt'] = startPos;
  }
  if (endPos != undefined) {
    details['endAt'] = endPos;
  }
  var request = gapi.client.youtube.playlistItems.insert({
    part: 'snippet',
    resource: {
      snippet: {
        playlistId: playlistId,
        resourceId: details
      }
    }
  });
  request.execute(function(response) {
    $('#status').html('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(response.result) + '</pre>');
  });
}
```

Finally, create the file "auth.js" -- this is the code that actually does the oAuth2 flow:

```
// The client id is obtained from the Google APIs Console at https://code.google.com/apis/console
// If you run access this code from a server other than http://localhost, you need to register
// your own client id.
var OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = '__YOUR_CLIENT_ID__';
var OAUTH2_SCOPES = [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube'
];

// This callback is invoked by the Google APIs JS client automatically when it is loaded.
googleApiClientReady = function() {
  gapi.auth.init(function() {
    window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 1);
  });
}

// Attempt the immediate OAuth 2 client flow as soon as the page is loaded.
// If the currently logged in Google Account has previously authorized OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID, then
// it will succeed with no user intervention. Otherwise, it will fail and the user interface
// to prompt for authorization needs to be displayed.
function checkAuth() {
  gapi.auth.authorize({
    client_id: OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
    scope: OAUTH2_SCOPES,
    immediate: true
  }, handleAuthResult);
}

// Handles the result of a gapi.auth.authorize() call.
function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
  if (authResult) {
    // Auth was successful; hide the things related to prompting for auth and show the things
    // that should be visible after auth succeeds.
    $('.pre-auth').hide();
    loadAPIClientInterfaces();
  } else {
    // Make the #login-link clickable, and attempt a non-immediate OAuth 2 client flow.
    // The current function will be called when that flow is complete.
    $('#login-link').click(function() {
      gapi.auth.authorize({
        client_id: OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
        scope: OAUTH2_SCOPES,
        immediate: false
        }, handleAuthResult);
    });
  }
}

// Loads the client interface for the YouTube Analytics and Data APIs.
// This is required before using the Google APIs JS client; more info is available at
// http://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/wiki/GettingStarted#Loading_the_Client
function loadAPIClientInterfaces() {
  gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() {
    handleAPILoaded();
  });
}
```

Note in there the OAUTH2_SCOPES constant. It's set to allow full management access, so if you then visit the html page in your browser and click on the 'authorize' link, you should see the window asking you to grant your domain access to manage your YouTube account. Do this, and then the code becomes functional ... you can add playlists and playlist items to your heart's content.

If you, however, then modify auth.js so that the OAUTH2_SCOPES looks like this:

```
var OAUTH2_SCOPES = [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly'
];
```

and clear your cookies (to avoid inheriting the permissions you already granted ... just closing the browser and relaunching ought to be enough), then try again (visit the HTML, click the authorize link), you'll see that this time it's asking you to grant permission only to VIEW the account rather than manage it. If you grant that permission, then when you try to add a playlist through the interface you'll get an error message appearing that says you can't create the playlist.

If you're not using javascript, but instead a server-side language, as I mentioned the gapi clients are quite smooth. However, the handling of oAuth2 scope in these clients is not quite as transparent, and they're by design 'greedy' (in that, as it abstracts a service endpoint to an object, it will request the most thorough scope it needs to do any of the actions at that endpoint ... so even if you only intend to do list calls, if the service has an update action as well the client will request full management privileges). This can be modified, though, if you want to get into the client code -- or you could use it as a model for creating your own simplified client that you can granularly control in terms of scope.

That's about as thorough as I can be without knowing your underlying technologies. Hope the explanation helps!

Comment: Thanks Jim. I have just started using the API and will need more time to understand the details. To give you more details I have one small portal that is used to generate the Token (client uses this portal) and we then use this token to pull data using the YT API and that is a separate process. Are you saying that https://googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly can be used. Do you have some code to share. I have gone through some posts/documentation on net that says this is possible only in Data API V 3.0 and Analytics API V 3.0